# SQL Server Updating from a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, updates, table-variable

**Final Edit - Solved - Solution Below**

I can't believe that I didn't know this, but apparently the issue was that the table variable and the real table both had the same name:  @CHECKERS and dbo.CHECKERS.  The trigger was apparently confusing the two.  I discovered this by changing the order of the insert and update operations in the trigger such that the insertion to the real table happens after the update from the table variable.  Suddenly, the updates began passing without issue.

Of course, I only created dbo.CHECKERS to debug @CHECKERS, so clearly some original problem existed which started this all; but regardless, the problem has been resolved and the trigger works just fine.  I'm posting it below, so feel free to offer any feedback if you wish.  I'm not an expert (clearly), and am always happy to receive constructive feedback.

Thanks everyone for your help and comments. I hope this post helps someone out there avoid a headache...

**Query - Solution**

```
ALTER TRIGGER CatchChange ON [dbo].[Orders]

-- Last Updated : 07 Oct 2014

AFTER UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
-- Trigger not fired by agent updates
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(UpdateRecordDate)
    -- Trigger fired only by user updates that include a timestamp.
    -- Does **NOT** fire from primary stored procedure (dictated by UpdateRecordDate).
    BEGIN

        -- Table variable for storing **multi-row updates**
        -- Using scalar variables will not work! Look it up.
        DECLARE @CHECKERS AS TABLE 
        (   OrderNum INT,
            Old_DCB INT,
            New_DCB INT,
            Old_MC INT,
            New_MC INT,
            Old_P2 NUMERIC(28,3),
            New_P2 NUMERIC(28,3),
            Old_PQ NUMERIC(28,3),
            New_PQ NUMERIC(28,3),
            Old_QT NUMERIC(28,3),
            New_QT NUMERIC(28,3)
        )

        -- Old & new values populated to table variable.
        -- We can add a table in the same format as the variable &
        -- then check what values were passed, if necessary.
        -- The INSERT for this scenario is commented out at the end.
        INSERT INTO @CHECKERS
        SELECT  I.OrderNo,
                D.DriverCB,
                I.DriverCB,
                D.MCode,
                I.MCode,
                D.Price2,
                I.Price2,
                D.PriceQuantity2,
                I.PriceQuantity2,
                D.Quantity1,
                I.Quantity1
        FROM Inserted I
        JOIN Deleted D ON I.Orderno = D.OrderNo
        -- These checks are crucial, as they cut down on reiteration.
        -- Without them, the program would fire the trigger redundantly.
        -- Here we check for changes to the relevant values &
        -- ensure that the update was a new one, not a repetitive one.
        WHERE I.OrderKind = 0
        AND isnull(D.UpdateRecordDate,convert(DATETIME,0)) <> isnull(I.UpdateRecordDate,convert(DATETIME,0))
        AND (D.DriverCB <> I.DriverCB
            OR D.MCode <> I.MCode
            OR D.Price2 <> I.Price2
            OR D.PriceQuantity2 <> I.PriceQuantity2
            OR D.Price3 <> I.Price3
            OR D.PriceQuantity3 <> I.PriceQuantity3
            OR D.Quantity1 <> I.Quantity1)

        -- Case conditions are preferable in this instance to IF conditions.
        -- All relevant values are checked here against dictating conditions &
        -- updated accordingly.
        UPDATE O
        SET     
        O.DriverCB =        CASE
                            WHEN C.New_DCB = 0
                            THEN NULL
                            ELSE O.DriverCB
                            END,
                            <...>,
        O.Quantity4 =       CASE 
                            WHEN C.New_QT > 0
                            THEN O.Quantity1
                            ELSE O.Quantity4
                            END 
        FROM Orders O
        INNER JOIN @CHECKERS C ON O.OrderNo = C.OrderNum

        -- This is the INSERT which populates the debug table, if you want.
        -- Naturally, the name here must match the name of the created table!
        -- And yes, DD, you need to create the ACTUAL TABLE outside of this trigger. :)
/*      INSERT INTO CheckMe
        SELECT  C.ID,
        C.OrderNum,
        C.Old_DriverCodeBizua,
        C.New_DriverCodeBizua,
        C.Old_MaslulCode1,
        C.New_MaslulCode1,
        C.Old_Price2,
        C.New_Price2,
        C.Old_PriceQuntity2,
        C.New_PriceQuntity2,
        C.Old_Quntity,
        C.New_Quntity
        FROM @CHECKERS C    */
    END
END
GO
```

**End Query - Solution**

*--------Begin Original Post--------*

*I have a customer who needs me to touch up a bunch of old triggers that perform various functions.  Generally, I'm not in favor of this and think their program should be updated - but whatever.*

*Three triggers exist, and I simply need to combine them into a single trigger that works a little more smoothly and has a few more conditions.  (Presently, a total lack of conditions makes the trigger run at every operation, which is painfully slow to watch.)*

*In short, I have created a new trigger in which I declare a table variable (query below).  I do this to give myself direct control over column names rather than simply using a SELECT X INTO #temp.  Thereafter, I am attempting to use CASE checks to update various fields in the main table dependent upon the changes logged in my table variable.*

*The problem is that the update doesn't do anything.  I get no errors, but the values in the main table remain the same.  To ensure that the table variable is getting values and that they are available for use, I added a new table to the test database and at each fire of the trigger I insert the values currently contained in the table variable to the new table, like this:*

```
        DECLARE @CHECKERS AS TABLE
        (   OrderNum INT,
            Old_DCB INT,
            New_DCB INT,
            Old_MC INT,
            New_MC INT,
            Old_QT NUMERIC(28,3),
            New_QT NUMERIC(28,3)
        )

        INSERT INTO @CHECKERS
        SELECT  I.OrderNo,
                D.DriverCB,
                I.DriverCB,
                D.MCode,
                I.MCode,
                D.Quantity,
                I.Quantity
        FROM Inserted I
        JOIN Deleted D ON I.OrderNo = D.OrderNo
        WHERE I.OrderKind = 0
        AND (D.DriverCB <> I.DriverCB
            OR D.MCode1 <> I.MCode1
            OR D.Quantity <> I.Quantity)

        INSERT INTO CHECKERS
        SELECT  OrderNum,
            Old_DCB,
            New_DCB,
            Old_MC,
            New_MC,
            Old_QT,
            New_QT
        FROM @CHECKERS
        -- An actual table created to check functionality
        -- Works up until this point

        UPDATE Orders
        SET Quantity2 = CASE 
                WHEN New_QT > 0 THEN New_QT
                ELSE Quantity2
                END
        FROM @CHECKERS C
        WHERE OrderNo = C.OrderNum
```

*Naturally, there are many more updates in the actual trigger, but you get the idea.*

*Any ideas why the update to Orders doesn't go through? Probably something small, silly, and embarassing - but again I say, whatever ;) Thanks.*

*--------End Original Post--------*

-- Edit:

I have also tried writing the update as such:

```
        UPDATE O
        SET Quantity2 = CASE 
                WHEN C.New_QT > 0 THEN C.New_QT
                ELSE Quantity2
                END
        FROM @CHECKERS C
        INNER JOIN Orders O on O.OrderNo = C.OrderNum
```

This approach gives the same result: No error message (or any other message, for that matter), and no update...

-- 2nd Edit:

**If I use the actual table CHECKERS rather than the table variable @CHECKERS, the update passes:**

```
            UPDATE O
            SET Quantity2 = CASE 
                    WHEN C.New_QT > 0 THEN C.New_QT
                    ELSE Quantity2
                    END
            FROM CHECKERS C -- Actual table, not a table variable!
            INNER JOIN Orders O on O.OrderNo = C.OrderNum
```

**This also works regardless of the presence of Orders in a JOIN:**

```
UPDATE Orders
            SET Quantity2 = CASE 
                    WHEN C.New_QT > 0 THEN C.New_QT
                    ELSE Quantity2
                    END
            FROM CHECKERS C -- Actual table, not a table variable!
            WHERE OrderNo = C.OrderNum
```

The only problem now is that, in the customer's database, I cannot add the real table CHECKERS.  I added it in my test database only to clarify whether or not the values were passing into the table variable! Is this a restriction of table variables that I am not familiar with? I'm having a hard time finding any such limitation in the online documentation...

Comment: If you do a select instead of update query, do you see the rows that should be updated?

Comment: What message do you see after the `UPDATE` statement? `UPDATE 0` perhaps? Or maybe something different?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, I see the rows that are intended to be updated if I switch to a select statement.

Comment: @nobodynoone That's just the thing - I receive NO message whatsoever.  If I were getting a message, at least I would have some clue what the problem might be...unfortunately, nothing.

Comment: Is your trigger on the table `Orders`? What type of trigger is it? Can you post the actual update statement that isn't working, the one you have posted would generate an error message `The multi-part identifier "O.OrderNo" could not be bound.`

Comment: @BenK I can't find alias `O` for your table `Orders` in `UPDATE` statement. Also, is the column name really `Quntity2` ? Misspelled name in database?

Comment: Sorry, sorry! Simple typo.  The column name is Quantity, not Quntity (my bad).  Same story with the notation.  The trigger is an AFTER UPDATE trigger. I'll update the query now.

Comment: @GarethD I've had to rename some of the tables a bit to make the query clearer because the actual names of the columns in the database are a mix of English and two other languages, which results in column names that are very clumsy.  Sorry for the typos - the example has been updated to reflect the actual trigger.

Comment: It is not a limitation of table variables, the only possibility I can see is that `@Checkers` does not contain any rows when the update is executed. Now from the code posted I cannot tell why, either rows are never inserted, or rows are deleted after being inserted. Are you able to create a simple ddl on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: @GarethD You were right, in an odd sort of way.  Apparently, during the process of checking, I managed to fix the problem; but I was not aware of this because I had a table variable CHECKERS and a real table CHECKERS.  The database confused the two, or so it would seem -- once I dropped the real table CHECKERS, the updates began to pass.  Too bad for me that now I can't know what the original problem was, but I will post the updated query so that others can look it over...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Orders in FROM statement as INNER JOIN.
Try this:

```
UPDATE O
SET Quantity2 = CASE 
        WHEN New_QT > 0 THEN New_QT
        ELSE Quantity2
        END
FROM @CHECKERS C
INNER JOIN Orders O on O.OrderNo = C.OrderNum
```

Comment: I'm glad that you pointed this out, but unfortunately this was the original structure of the trigger.  I have updated the post to indicate this.  Even with the INNER JOIN (or any other JOIN, including even a FULL OUTER JOIN), the update still does not affect Orders.  Still, I much prefer explicit JOINS to implicit ones, so thank you for that response.

Answer (score 0):

The table variable (@CHECKERS) and the actual table (dbo.CHECKERS) have the same name.  The trigger got confused between them.  By changing the order of the operations in the trigger, this became obvious.  I then changed the name of the actual table and everything began working a lot more smoothly.

I did not know this about table variables, nor did I find it anywhere online in a few hours of searching for a solution.

For general info: This trigger was created in Microsoft SQL Server 2005.  Perhaps the issue has been resolved, or perhaps this was a fluke.  Either way, changing the name of dbo.CHECKERS to dbo.CHECKME solved the issue for me.